# Ask user for reason when flagging as Low Quality

Tags: feature-request

What I'm proposing should be pretty clear from the title. Have users pick one from a list of reasons when flagging a post as low quality, just like with flagging as off topic.

There are a few reasons why I think this should be useful. First off, often times, while going through the Low Quality Post review queue, I'll come across answers which seem completely fine. Some might have a downvote or two, and many are code only answers. In order to actually know if the post is low quality, I have to go through the question, try and understand what the OP is asking, decide if I know enough about the subject judge the answer or else skip it etc. Having users give a reason when flagging would speed this process up a lot.

An additional benefit this would have is stop people from using the Low Quality flag for the wrong reasons. Having to pick from a list of reasons and finding none that match would lead them to reconsider which flag, if any, is appropriate for that situation. This would for example reduce the massive amount of code-only answers which get dumped into the queue every day which, while admitedly not very good, are correct and thus not deserving of deletion.

Comment: A very large portion of those code only answers are coming from the queue automatically putting them in, not because people have flagged the post.

Comment: @Servy That is interesting. What is the decision to put them in the queue based on?

Comment: You *don't* need to understand the question and the merits of the answer to evaluate a post in the LQP queue.  Any post that would merit deletion from that queue is going to be obviously meeting the relevant criteria *regardless of the question or any technical merits of an answer*.  If you've gotten far enough to start judging an answer on it's technical merits, you've *already* demonstrated that it's not VLQ.

Comment: Various unspecified/underspecified heuristics for low quality posts, for which certain types of code only answers are a known false positive.

Comment: I will at least not get cranky at seeing all the code only answers in that queue knowing that they were most likely automatically placed there. (I will continue to get cranky at seeing wrong answers but I don't even thing a dialog will prevent that.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is really needed.  There are currently only 2 flags that put posts into the LQPRQ.  They are

> #### not an answer
>
> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.
>
> #### very low quality
>
> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

IMHO, that is not a lot of things to check.  If they are flagging something just because it is low quality then the correct thing to do is decline that.  If they get enough declined flags they will get flagged banned and can review their flags to see where they are being to stringent.

---

As far as the code only answer those are put there by the system.  If you can understand them then they are most likely an answer.  The code doesn't have t be right, that is not what you're there to judge.  You're there to make sure it is an answer.  One thing you can do is get something like [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) and use a comment like

> While this code may answer the question it would be a lot better if you include an explanation with it.  Remember that your answer is not just for the OP but it is also for all the other people that might have this issue and they might not understand how this code is supposed to fix it.